# Spring Batch dynamic chunk size based on the number of rows from a CSV without counting the header row

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, chunking

My application is a scheduled job runner with batch configurations.

I can have CSV files with different number of rows, but I know that the first row will be always the header:

```
id,firstName,lastName
1,Viktor,Someone
2,Joe,Smith
3,Rebecca,Harper
```

How should I set up the chunk to be dynamic? The file can contain 5, 10, or even 100000 rows.

So instead of giving a big number to the chunk, I am looking for a better **dynamic solution based on the number of the rows without counting the header row**!

```
@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Employee, Employee>chunk(100000)
            .reader(reader())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}
```

The reader is a `FlatFileItemReader`.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

```
@Bean
public Step step1() {
   long lineNumberWithoutHeader = Files.lines(Paths.get("path to your file")).count() - 1;
   int chunkSize = .. // calculate chunk size based on lineNumberWithoutHeader
   return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Employee, Employee>chunk(chunkSize)
        .reader(reader())
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
}
```

You can refactor the code as needed (inject the file resource or late bind it from job parameters, extract the calculation logic in a separate method, etc), but you got the idea.

Another option would be to use a separate step that does the calculation and put it in the job execution context, then configure your chunk-oriented step with the value from the execution context.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I thought about it also, but it is so ugly that I read the file in the configuration also.

Comment: You are not reading the file, you are just counting the lines to be able to dynamically calculate the chunk size. This is what your requirement is, isn't it? So you need to do that calculation somewhere. As I said, refactor the code to make it cleaner, but I would keep it simple and stupid. Otherwise, create a separate step as mentioned in the answer if you don't want to do it in the config. You can also do it in a listener. If you run on unix/linux, you can also do something like `wc -l your_file.csv` and pass the number of lines as a job parameter and use it in the step configuration.